# how to separate strings based on semicolon

Tags: r

I have a data

```
india1;india-2;india3
coreanorth1;corea
gdyijq;udyhfs
gdyijq;udyhfs;gqdtr
USA;America1
```

The dput can be found here

```
df <- structure(list(india1.india.2.india3 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("coreanorth1;corea", 
"gdyijq;udyhfs", "gdyijq;udyhfs;gqdtr", "USA;America1"), class = "factor")), .Names = "india1.india.2.india3", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

what I am trying to do is to split them and put them either under each other

```
india1        1
india-2       1
india3        1
coreanorth1   2
corea         2
 gdyijq       3
udyhfs        3
 gdyijq       3
udyhfs        4
gqdtr         4
USA           5
America1      5
```

Comment: `unlist(str_split(df[,1], ";"))`?

Comment: Your `df` has `india1.india.2.india3` as a column name?

Comment: @thelatemail no they are not column name, they are strings

Comment: @nik - not according to your `dput`

Comment: @Mike H it seems very nice but then I don't know how to add the number , do you see in front of my output?

Comment: @thelatemail OK, change the column name to for example **names(df)[1]<-"columnX"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit:* Changed `sapply` to get the lengths to `lengths` as per @thelatemail's comment.
Using exactly the input data you provide a solution would be:

```
spl <- str_split(df[,1], ";");
res <- data.frame(split = unlist(spl), 
                  count = rep(1:length(spl), times = lengths(spl)))
   #         split count
   # 1 coreanorth1     1
   # 2       corea     1
   # 3      gdyijq     2
   # 4      udyhfs     2
   # 5      gdyijq     3
   # 6      udyhfs     3
   # 7       gqdtr     3
   # 8         USA     4
   # 9    America1     4
```

Note that your input data had the "india..." character as the name of the column which is why it's not getting added.

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I reckon should be done - though you can replace `sapply(spl, length)` with `lengths(spl)` And you can avoid a dependency if you use `strsplit` instead of `str_split` - or at least you should load the necessary library.

Comment: Oh nice, never knew `lengths` existed! I'll update my answer

Comment: Works for those of us following from home, but OP has, essentially two different string splits (one, as @thelatemail  and dput) have as column name, and then in OP output it is, well output so the counting is off.

Answer (score 1):

Tought one! This works:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  string = c("india1;india-2;india3",
  "coreanorth1;corea",
  "gdyijq;udyhfs",
  "gdyijq;udyhfs;gqdtr",
  "USA;America1"))

df %>% 
  mutate(string = as.character(string),
         row = 1:n(),
         string = strsplit(string, ";")) %>% 
  unnest(string)
```

gives me:

```
   row      string
1    1      india1
2    1     india-2
3    1      india3
4    2 coreanorth1
5    2       corea
6    3      gdyijq
7    3      udyhfs
8    4      gdyijq
9    4      udyhfs
10   4       gqdtr
11   5         USA
12   5    America1
```

Comment: thanks Dan , it sounds very nice but I don't want to change the structure of the input data as you did

Comment: @nik - what is the structure of your input then? Because what Dan uses is pretty much identical to the `dput` of your `df`. With the exception that the column is named `string` instead of the first row of data being incorrectly inserted as a header.

Comment: @nik Yep, I just cleaned yours up a bit, if you want to use your df, just substitute `string` with `india1.india.2.india3` in all 5 places and it will work